# Issues with Crypto.generateMac() in SalesForce APEX

Tags: oauth, salesforce, force.com

We need to make a few callouts to a service that is using OAuth 1.0 and requires each request to be signed with HMAC-SHA1.

The service doesn't have any APEX client API. Thus, we have to do it manually.

Unfortunately,

```
EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA1', Blob.valueOf(data), Blob.valueOf(key)));
```

returns a different string from what we expect. We have compared the output for the same input with libraries for other languages. And the output was different.

Comment: can you give an example of how its different, it it just base64 vs hex encoding?

Comment: It would definitely help if you supplied an example of what you are seeing: an input and the two different outputs. I have been using HmacSHA256 signing via Apex with no issues for quite some time.

Answer (score 2):

I have no problems calling out to OAuth 1.0. Here's some sample Apex for signing your request:

EDIT: Added additional code

```
private Map<String,String> getUrlParams(String value) 
{
    Map<String,String> res = new Map<String,String>();
    if(value==null || value=='') 
    {
        return res;
    }
    for(String s : value.split('&')) 
    {
        List<String> kv = s.split('=');
        if(kv.size()>1) 
        {
            res.put(kv[0],kv[1]);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

private String createBaseString(Map<String,String> oauthParams, HttpRequest req) 
{
    Map<String,String> p = oauthParams.clone();
    if(req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase('post') && req.getBody()!=null && req.getHeader('Content-Type')=='application/x-www-form-urlencoded') 
        p.putAll(getUrlParams(req.getBody()));
    String host = req.getEndpoint();
    Integer n = host.indexOf('?');
    if(n > -1) 
    {
        p.putAll(getUrlParams(host.substring(n+1)));
        host = host.substring(0,n);
    }
    List<String> keys = new List<String>();
    keys.addAll(p.keySet());
    keys.sort();
    String s = keys.get(0)+'='+p.get(keys.get(0));
    for(Integer i=1; i<keys.size(); i++) 
        s = s + '&' + keys.get(i) + '=' + p.get(keys.get(i));

    return req.getMethod().toUpperCase() + '&' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(host, 'UTF-8') + '&' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(s, 'UTF-8');
}

public void sign(HttpRequest req) 
{
   nonce = String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomLong());
   timestamp = String.valueOf(DateTime.now().getTime() / 1000);

   refreshParameters();

   String s = createBaseString(parameters, req);
   Blob sig = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA1', Blob.valueOf(s), 
      Blob.valueOf(consumerSecret+'&'+ (tokenSecret!=null ? tokenSecret : '')));

   signature = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64encode(sig), 'UTF-8');

   String header = 'OAuth ';
   for (String key : parameters.keySet()) 
   {
      header = header + key + '="'+parameters.get(key)+'", ';
   }
   header = header + 'oauth_signature="'+signature+'"';
   req.setHeader('Authorization',header);
}
```

This might be reaching, but could there be a case-sensitivity issue? Notice I'm calling 'HmacSHA1' not 'hmacSHA1'

Comment: Hi @adam, this is nice, am trying to encrypt using this generatemac, how do we decrypt this using our own custom private key??? Can you please post a sample code?